# Why does this code using MySQLi throw a PHP Notice : trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

This code works, and outputs an array as intended, but throws the following error message:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object...

Here is my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","database");
$sql = "SELECT keyterm
    FROM keyterms";
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($result = $results->fetch_object()->keyterm)
    $keyterms[] = $result;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fetch_object()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) will return null when there are no more results in your result set, so the last iteration of the while loop will attempt to access the `keyterm` property on a null value.

You should assign the result object to `$result` and then access the property in the loop body, e.g.:

```
while($result = $results->fetch_object())
    $keyterms[] = $result->keyterm;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$keyterms = array();
if ($results  = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
  while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
  {
    $keyterms[] = $obj->keyterm;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get that warning because you look up the property **before** checking if the cursor returns a valid object. In other words on the last iteration when the recordset has been exhausted, you will have an empty object with no `keyterm` property.